# Overwrite css classes in antd select

Tags: reactjs, antd

With the below code I'm trying to remove padding around the select options. In the screenshot below we could see padding around names while we hover.

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-5-1-6-forked-41s3yb?file=/demo.tsx

[image]

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./index.css";
import { Select, Space } from "antd";

const handleChange = (value: string) => {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
};

const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
  .ant-select-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
`;

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <Space wrap>
    <StyledSelect
      defaultValue="lucy"
      style={{ width: 120 }}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={[
        { value: "jack", label: "Jack" },
        { value: "lucy", label: "Lucy" },
        { value: "Yiminghe", label: "yiminghe" }
      ]}
    />
  </Space>
);

export default App;
```

On inspecting I saw .ant-select-dropdown-menu has a padding of 4px , but I need some help in overwriting that class to 0px. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `antd` [document](https://ant.design/components/select), the prop `dropdownStyle` can be used to style the dropdown menu with CSS properties.

To remove the `padding` for the dropdown, perhaps try add `dropdownStyle={{ padding: "0px" }}` as the prop of `Select`.

Forked demo with modification: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-5-1-6-forked-0fpqrp?file=/demo.tsx)

```
<Select
  defaultValue="lucy"
  //  Added this
  dropdownStyle={{ padding: "0px" }}
  style={{ width: 120 }}
  onChange={handleChange}
  options={[
    { value: "jack", label: "Jack" },
    { value: "lucy", label: "Lucy" },
    { value: "Yiminghe", label: "yiminghe" },
  ]}
/>
```